# Require EventEmitter compatible with Node and React-Native

Tags: node.js, events, module, npm, react-native

I am using an npm package which requires the events module like this

```
var EE = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

This fails in React Native because the events module can't be found. How can this be fixed?
I know that I can do `var EE = require('EventEmitter');` in react-native but what would be the correct way for an npm package to handle this (i.e. be compatible with node and react-native)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install events -g --save`

Would you mind sharing your package.json file and some background of what you hope to accomplish? I don't have much insight into what you're doing but providing the error messages you're getting + a summary of what you're doing would be huge